# What do we want to do about blog being discontinued?

Tags: discussion, blog

StackExchange is looking to discontinue *all* community blogs, including [our own](http://cstheory.blogoverflow.com). They are asking what we want to be done with our old posts (for example, migration to 3rd parties). **Does anybody have opinions on this?** I am interested in the opinion of post authors and the editors, in particular.

Our blog hasn't seen new posts in over 4 years, and is unlikely to see new ones at this rate. However, I know that a [number of us](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/22226/1037) run our own active blogs. So we might be interested in migrating our posts. For example, I have migrated/adapted my two posts on [quantum query complexity](https://egtheory.wordpress.com/2013/12/09/quantum-query-complexity/) ([original](http://cstheory.blogoverflow.com/2011/07/quantum-query-complexity/)) and the [negative adversary method](https://egtheory.wordpress.com/2013/12/16/negative-adversary-method/) ([original](http://cstheory.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/lower-bounds-by-negative-adversary-method/)) over to my own blog nearly three years ago.

As a possible option, the blog I run -- [TheEGG](https://egtheory.wordpress.com) -- is a community project and has over 18 contributors. I would be happy to welcome any of the non-time specific (i.e. not the old conference announcements/dissections) posts over to my blog if their authors don't run their own blogs (or think it fits poorly with their more narrow theme). I would stagger their (re)release over the coming weeks. If they are interested, I might make slight stylistic edit suggestions to the respective authors to make their post(s) fit better with TheEGG's readership. If you are interested in having your post go this route, either respond in the comments here or email me at: lastname (dot) firstname (at) gmail (dot) com.

As a second, low effort, option: We can simply convert the blog to static pages that would remain on servers that SE manages.

Comment: I don't have an opinion as I never participated, but I guess the most simple solution would be to move the whole thing to a blog provider capable of Markdown (e.g. Github Pages) and have SE forward there. (That is, if they *do* keep at least the domain.)

Comment: It may also be prudent to contact communities with more active blogs; maybe a consensus solution can be found. It would make the most sense, in a way, if all blogs migrated to the same platform.

Comment: @Raphael I think trying to continue the blog as a blog for this site is unsustainable. There is just not enough commitment to it from our users. As for archival purposes, I would vote for archiving on more 'live' blogs (like personal blogs) than creating a dead blog on github to go stale with no new updates.

Comment: more on the SE decision [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291741/we-will-no-longer-be-hosting-blog-overflow). would really like to see a (well-supported) community blog for this site myself however there are many other high quality TCS blogs in existence. [Narayanan TCS aggregator](http://feedworld.net/toc/) has great coverage etc

Comment: I would move to static pages for all of the old blog posts and have our old posts point to that . And after that we could have some aggregate blog that we would point to in the future .